# Has anyone studied this possible generalisation of the Singular Value Decomposition to all commutative $*$-rings?

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

I don't know any abstract algebraists personally, which is why I'm asking this question here.

Let $(R,*)$ be a commutative $*$-ring where $*:R \to R$ is an involution. Each conjecture below is stated individually for each commutative $*$-ring.

Consider the following three notions:

> **Naive SVD**: A matrix $M$ has a naive SVD if it can be factorised as $M = U S V^*$ where $S$ is a Hermitian and diagonal matrix.

Over some rings, many matrices, including some invertible ones, may not have naive SVDs. For this reason, we introduce two different notions of *singular block decomposition* or *SBD*.

> **Strong $B$-SBD**: A matrix $M$ has a strong $B$-SBD if $M$ can be factorised as $M = U S V^*$ where $S$ is the direct sum of matrices in $B$. The multisubset of matrices in $B$ which forms $S$ must be unique, meaning that if $USV^* = U' S' (V')^*$ then $S = S'$ (in the sense that every matrix in $B$ which occurs in $S$ also occurs in $S'$ the same number of times). Additionally, *we require $B$ to consist of **only** Hermitian matrices*.

I conjecture that there exists a set $B$ of Hermitian matrices such a matrix has a strong $B$-SBD if and only if it has a polar decomposition.

> **Weak $B$-SBD**: This is the same as the strong $B$-SBD except we don't require $B$ to consist of Hermitian matrices.

I conjecture that there exists a set $B$ such that every matrix has a weak $B$-SBD.

My question is: Have these notions been studied? Are these conjectures easy to prove? I imagine the Axiom of Choice can help select the matrices in $B$, but I haven't fleshed this out.